# Execute method by decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I would like to execute a function by a decorator with the current component `this` after angular run DI.

An example:

If execute on decorator, I don't have translateService on `this`

```
export const TesteDecorator = (actionName): any => {

  return (target?: any, propertyKey?: string): void => {

    Observable.timer(5000).subscribe(() => {
      target[propertyKey](); // when i execute here not have translateService on (this)
    });

  };
};
```

But if execute on constructor have the translateService .

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class TesteComponent {

  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) {
    Observable.timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
      this.teste(); // when i execute here translateService is on the (this)
    });
  }

  @TesteDecorator('ACTION')
  teste() {
    console.log(this);
  }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the decorator is executed on class declaration and `target` is not an instance of the class but it's prototype, so it will not contain any fields.

One approach to  get around this would be to wrap an existing function to invoke your extra code, and call the method from the constructor:

```
export const TesteDecorator = (actionName): any => {

    return (target?: any, propertyKey?: string): void => {
        var prevFn: ()=> void = target['testeDecoratorHelper'];
        target['testeDecoratorHelper'] = function() {
            prevFn.call(this);
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(propertyKey);
                this[propertyKey](); // when i execute here not have translateService on (this)
            }, 10);
        }   

    };
};

export class TesteComponent {
    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
        this.testeDecoratorHelper();   
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.teste(); // when i execute here translateService is on the (this)
        }, 10);
    }
    testeDecoratorHelper() {
    }
    @TesteDecorator('ACTION')
    teste() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    @TesteDecorator('ACTION')
    teste2() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

The implementation above does not work with derived types, but it shoud get you started.

**Edit**

Since you are using Angular, instead of `testeDecoratorHelper` you could also use `ngOnInit` which has the advantage of being invoked automatically so you don't have to invoke it from the constructor. (10x to estus for this suggestions)

Comment: A more seamless way is to patch ngOnInit (as long as this doesn't create race conditions).